# MS SQL Recursive Stored Procedure To Group Based Off Of User Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by, cursor

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the best way to group users together based off of their attributes.

Here's a simplified version of some user data:

```
ID | First Name | Last Name | Address | Email | Phone 1 | Phone 2 | Phone 3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Bob          Smith       Addy 1    a@a     1         2         3
2    Susan        Q           Addy 2    b@b     4         5         6
3    Robert       Smith                 a@a     1
4    Susie        Quinn       Addy 2
5    Ryan         Foo         Addy 3    c@c
6    Pat          Bar         Addy 4
7    Patrick      Bar         Addy 4            1         2         3
```

From that, I can tell that the grouped items will look like:

```
1,3 (Matched on email)
2,4 (Matched on address)
5 (no matches)
6,7 (Matched on Address and last name)
1,7 (Matched on all three phone numbers)
```

I'm able to get this far with the stored procedure I've written.  This results in 2.6 million results.  Now, the next step I need to take is to merge these into non-duplicate groups... which should look something like this:

```
1,3,6,7
2,4
5
```

I've tested out a cursor query but, after 30 minutes of execution, it hadn't finished.  So my question is this: what's the best/most efficient way to turn my 1 to 1 matches into one to many matches?

Comment: I would avoid cursors (they are slow and lame) and implement using a combination of table-valued functions and stored procedures. Your real problem is identifying when you've completed the merge process.

Comment: If you have 2.6 million results and you have a handful of fields, then each row is going to be really, really long.  This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm going end up creating a guid and then store each ID in column #2... not adding it all together on the root source.